# Converter variaveis numericas qualitativas em fatores no R

Tags: r

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo ja PRONTO, que meu orientador passou para mim

```
fatores=c("Year","Month","DayofWeek","DayofMonth")

dadosFatores=apply(dados[,fatores],2,XXXX)

dados[,XXXX]=dadosFatores
```

No exercicio diz que eu devo trocar apenas os `XXXX` por algo que faça sentido e retorne o que a função pede, ou seja, converter as variaveis em questao em fatores.

Eu tentei substituir por `as.factor`, sem grande sucesso.

Alguem poderia ajudar ?

Comment: Você pode mostrar um pedaço da variável dados? É um data frame, uma matriz? Existem outras colunas além daquelas listadas no vetor fatores?

Answer (score 4):

Alterando minha resposta, na verdade há um problema anterior, você teria que utilizar o `lapply` ao invés do `apply`, porque aparentemente o `apply` vai jogar tudo para uma matriz e converter para `character` antes de retornar para o `data.frame` (não tinha testado o código antes).

Gerando um dado fictício para ilustrar:

```
dados <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
dados[, fatores] <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"),10)
str(dados)
data.frame':    10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Year      : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ Month     : chr  "c" "d" "a" "b" ...
 $ DayofWeek : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ DayofMonth: chr  "c" "d" "a" "b" ...
```

Com `apply` (não funciona):

```
dados[,fatores]= apply(dados[,fatores], 2, as.factor)
str(dados)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Year      : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ Month     : chr  "c" "d" "a" "b" ...
 $ DayofWeek : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ DayofMonth: chr  "c" "d" "a" "b" ...
```

Com o `lapply` (funciona):

```
dados[,fatores]= lapply(dados[,fatores], as.factor)
str(dados)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Year      : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
 $ Month     : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
 $ DayofWeek : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2
 $ DayofMonth: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Se aparece algum erro no código acima, coloque a mensagem de erro e um exemplo reproduzível para podermos entender qual é o problema e o resultado de `head(dados)` e `str(dados)` na sua pergunta para vermos como é o objeto

Comment: Retirando o primeiro XXXX e colocando as.factor aparece isso aqui:

Erro em dados[, fatores] : número incorreto de dimensões

Comment: @Felipe Isso quer dizer que seu objeto dados não tem colunas ou outra coisa desse tipo. Coloque o resultado de `head(dados)` e `str(dados)` na sua pergunta para vermos como é o objeto.