# Como posso converter valores strings ou itens de uma coluna de objetos em binários com o pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando converter uma coluna em um conjunto de dados no qual há 'negativo' e 'positivo' para binários ou itens numeráveis como 0 e 1, mas não sei se estou fazendo isso direito com a biblioteca Pandas.

```
pd.cut(data.Class, bins=['negative','positive'],labels=['0','1'])
```

mas o seguinte erro aparece:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'negative'
```

Já tentei por boolean mask da seguinte forma:

```
mask = data['Class'] == 'negative'

data.loc[mask, 'Class'] = 0
data.loc[~mask, 'Class'] = 1
```

Mas aí ele converte todos em apenas um dos tipos!

Uma amostra da base de dados que estou utilizando é:

```
          v8      v9      Class  
0    0.00000  0.1224   negative  
1    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
2    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
3    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
4    0.00000  0.0561   negative  
..       ...     ...        ...  
166  0.66150  0.0000   negative  
167  1.06155  0.0000   negative  
168  1.62855  0.0000   negative  
169  1.71045  0.0000   positive  
170  1.54980  0.0000   positive
```

Eu gostaria que o resultado fosse o seguinte:

```
          v8      v9   Class  
0    0.00000  0.1224   0  
1    0.00000  0.0000   0  
2    0.00000  0.0000   0  
3    0.00000  0.0000   0  
4    0.00000  0.0561   0  
..       ...     ...    ...  
166  0.66150  0.0000   0  
167  1.06155  0.0000   0  
168  1.62855  0.0000   0  
169  1.71045  0.0000   1  
170  1.54980  0.0000   1
```

Comment: Isso é uma conversão de uma variável categórica em numérica. Como não achei uma pergunta sobre isso para pandas, respondi sua questão. Mas seria interessante mudar o título para refletir melhor o conteúdo da pergunta. Veja o caso dessa perguntá análoga feita para o R: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41889/converter-variaveis-numericas-qualitativas-em-fatores-no-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução usando `map`:

```py
data['Class'].map({'positive':1,'negative':0})
```

Note que essa solução serve para diversas categorias. No caso específico de variáveis binárias, existe o `get_dummies`. Para seu caso, o comando ficaria assim:

```py
pd.get_dummies(data['Class'])
```

O output será duas colunas. Cada uma usando uma das classes como referência. Escolha a que você preferir.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas já tentei anteriormente usar o map e não sei por quê os valores são transformados em nulos = NaN. Tentei novamente com essa sua dica e deu no mesmo. Esse get_dummies eu não conhecia e vou tentar utilizá-lo com o classificador. Porque estou tentando aplicar com One Class SVM.

Comment: Era para funcionar. Você pode disponibilizar os dados?

Comment: Os dados são da clássica base KEEL https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/imbalanced.php e pode ver na maioria dos datasets que as classes delas são denominadas com 'positive' e 'negative'.

Comment: Lucas, descobri! A maioria dessas bases tem dados com espaços em branco, então aconselham utilizar o parâmetro skipinitialspace = True na função read_csv.

Comment: Ok. Se estiver tudo certo e não restou nenhuma dúvida, por favor, marque a questão como resolvida, clicando em "✅".

Comment: Não há esse botão, então coloquei a tag Resolvido

Comment: o botão fica abaixo do contador de votos. Veja exemplo nessa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png